# Lerp point between position A,B while controlling the min and max Y-value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object A that I can move freely, and and object B that also moves freely but always along the ground.

I wrote some code to make a point always interpolate at 50% distance between A,B. I modified the code so that if object A goes below listenerMinY on the Y-axis, it will move closer to point A.

This all works great. However one more thing I want to add is that if object A goes above listenerMaxY on the Y-axis, the point cannot go any higher, in other words I want to Clamp the point to a position on the Y-axis. And I do not know how to do that using this Lerp.

As you can see I am currently trying to clamp the Y-position to listenerMaxY which does limit it's movement on the Y-axis, but then it does not interpolate correctly and leaves the "line" between A,B.

```
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, groundLayer))
        {
            downwardDistance = hit.distance;
        }
        //listenerMinY = 20, listenerMaxY = 60

        float percentageDistance = downwardDistance / listenerMinY;
        Vector3 interpolation = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, centerGround.position, Mathf.Clamp(percentageDistance, 0, .5f));
        
        point.position = new Vector3(interpolation.x, Mathf.Clamp(interpolation.y, 0, listenerMaxY), interpolation.z);
        point.rotation = transform.rotation;
```

Full code (attach to camera or any Object A) for testing:

```
public class CameraRay : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] LayerMask groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] Transform centerGround;
    [SerializeField] Transform listener;

    [SerializeField] int listenerMinY;
    [SerializeField] int listenerMaxY;


    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        float forwardDistance = 0;
        float downwardDistance = 0;

        // Control center ground pos
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, groundLayer))
        {
            forwardDistance = hit.distance;

            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * forwardDistance, Color.blue);
            centerGround.position = hit.point;
        }

        // Check distance Y from ground, green = <20, red = >listener Y limit, else yellow
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, groundLayer))
        {
            downwardDistance = hit.distance;

            if (downwardDistance < listenerMinY)
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * downwardDistance, Color.green);
            else if(downwardDistance < listenerMaxY)
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * downwardDistance, Color.yellow);
            else
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * downwardDistance, Color.red);
        }

        float percentageDistance = downwardDistance / listenerMinY;
        Vector3 interpolation = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, centerGround.position, Mathf.Clamp(percentageDistance, 0, .5f));
        
        listener.position = new Vector3(interpolation.x, Mathf.Clamp(interpolation.y, 0, listenerMaxY), interpolation.z);
        listener.rotation = transform.rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can just have sequence of `if (!Like(interpolated.Y)) interpolated = NextInterpoalationOption(original);` . To find coefficient for interpolation you need to solve something similar to "a.y + (b.y-a.y) * t =  listenerMinY" for t (depending on what exactly your conditions are - not really sure), but that part is not suitable Q for SO...

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to stay on the vector A -> B or in your specific case `centerGround.position` -> `transform.position` but whatever happens the `Y` component of he resulting vector should not be bigger than `listenerMaxY`.

So you can probably calculate backwards what factor you would need to maximum reach that Y level like e.g.

```
// returns the factor that would be needed to be passed into Lerp in order to result in listenerMaxY
// the result is clamped between 0 and 1
var maxFactor = Mathf.InverseLerp(transform.position.y, centerGround.position.y, listenerMaxY);
// your original factor based on the distance 
var percentageDistance = downwardDistance / listenerMinY;
// Now take the minimum of the two factors
var factor = Mathf.Min(percentageDistance, maxFactor);
// and use that as the factor of Lerp
var interpolation = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, centerGround.position, factor);

// The result is now always a position on the line between
// transform.position and centerGround.position but with y <= listenerMaxY
// (EXCEPT if both positions are already higher than that anyway of course)
listener.position = interpolation;
```

See [`Mathf.InverseLerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html) => basically as the name says this works exactly the other way round: Give it a start and end point and the expected value and it will return the factor that would result in that last value when passed into `Lerp`